# can not receiver broadcast from action com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

I have a issue with google billing redeem code. i registerReceiver broadcast from intent com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED
But i can not receiver broadcast when resume app after input redeem code on play store app. Method onReceive not call.

```
mBroadcastReceiver = new IabBroadcastReceiver(MainActivity.this);
                    IntentFilter broadcastFilter = new IntentFilter(IabBroadcastReceiver.ACTION);
                    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, broadcastFilter);
```

code class IabBroadcastReceiver

```
public class IabBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   public interface IabBroadcastListener {
    void receivedBroadcast();
}

/**
 * The Intent action that this Receiver should filter for.
 */
public static final String ACTION = "com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED";

private final IabBroadcastListener mListener;

public IabBroadcastReceiver(IabBroadcastListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.receivedBroadcast();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you need to add broadcast receiver to your manifest.

Refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) for more info.

Comment: Hello. i had add it in manifest. But this issue is still. what is wrong here?

<receiver android:name=".IabBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.IN_APP_NOTIFY"></action>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE"></action>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED"></action>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.billing.PURCHASES_UPDATED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>